# LDAP: error code 49 -NDS error: failed authentication (-669)" to connection"

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

Users of our application complain once in a while every couple of weeks that they are not able to login to application. After 10 to 15 minutes they are able to login successfully.The application has around 500 users. But, only some 10 to 15 get this issue sometime.
Our Authentication service shows the error message in log:

```
LDAP: error code 49 -NDS error: failed authentication (-669)" to connection"
```

Could the issue be in LDAP server or memory issue? Did some research on google and found https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=10073582 . It says "PublicKey and ACL is missing on the WebAccess_PCO object." But then no one should be able to login.

eDirectory version is 8.8.7

Comment: What version of eDirectory? How are you performing the bind? Code?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi jwilleke eDirectory version is 8.8.7 I don't have access to any code of the service authenticating. But will try to find and see if I can get something.

Comment: In eDirectory 8.8.7 the error code returned (-669) returns when DN or password/credential is invalid.

This assumes that No password Policy, Account Restrictions or Time Restrictions are involved.

This, along with the delay, might suggest that there are "other" conditions in play as Intruder Detection